# Lag when Redirecting from Default route to another route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to React Router and I'm working on the best way to route to react router.

**What am I trying to achieve:**

I just want the **default route** to navigate to `/:tenantName/media_management/dashboard` instead of `/:tenantName/media_management` when the Media Management tab is clicked.

**Issue:**

> - I'm explicitly checking if the route is initial route and then re-routing to `/dashboard`. This works but it's
>     very slow. I can notice the apparent lag when I click on
>     `Media-management` Tab.
> - **Wanted to know if there is a better way of handling default route?**

**Router.js**

```
import { Route, Redirect, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const AsyncMediaManagement = lazy(() => import('@src/features/media-management/'));


<Route
   path="/:tenantName/media_management"
   component={withMainLayout(AsyncMediaManagement, 'MediaManagement')}
/>
```

**Media-management.js:**

```
  if (contentTypeSelected === '') {
    props.history.push(`/:tenantName/media_management/dashboard`);
  }
```

Please help, I'm very new to react router and any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you push path to history, pages will route without hesitation. Perhaps it's something related with `lazy` or other code which is not been shown here.

Comment: If you want to redirect to another component/route, you can also add the condition inside of the current component's life-cycle `componentWillMount`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `exact=true` to your Routes

Can we see some more of your 's - do you have the default dashboard route above or below the one you have shown?

RR will match the first route that it finds if you don't add an `exact=true` prop to the route.

Comment: I don't have a default, I need to make a default route for this one. Can you shred some light with more info?

Comment: Add `<Route path="/:tenantName/media_management/dashboard" ... />` to your Switch

Comment: @Johnathan Irwin I'm trying to redirect from / to ..../dashboard .. how does adding this route help? Just curious

Comment: Well if you don't have a Route for that route I'm not sure how you are going to navigate the user there.

Comment: How are you navigating when a user clicks on the Media-Management tab? Because can't it just be a <Link to="/:tenantName/media_management/dashboard" />

Comment: Yes, it's a link for <Link to="/:tenantName/media_management" /> but i want to redirect it to `/media_management/dashboard` I'm trying to see if there is someway to route it rather than modifying my `<link>` or `<li>` element to directly reference to `/dashboard`

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand the issue. If you want to nav to /dashboard why not just update the Link to point there?